# Is there an existing implementation of the Short-Time Fourier Transformation in PHP?

Tags: php, signal-processing, fft, wav

I've been looking all over for a STFT implementation in PHP, but I can't find it anywhere and I'm not sure I trust myself to create one without making the complexity unnecessarily high.

I'm attempting to use this to alter the color of a waveform image I'm generating, similar to the color coding of audio signal visuals in DJ software like Traktor.

Does anybody know of a math library that might help with this?

Comment: Googling for "PHP FFT" seems to turn up plenty of options, e.g. http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6193-PHP-Compute-the-Fast-Fourier-Transform-of-sampled-data.html

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping to avoid using a base Fourier transform class to make a STFT implementation, but I might have to.

Comment: An FFT and an STFT are pretty much the same thing in practice - STFT just means that you apply an FFT to a block of your input data (usually a sliding window in the case of audio).